# Counting common elements in a list on that occur on same day in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame which looks like:

```
Users               Date
['A', 'B']        2017-10-21
['B', 'C']        2017-10-21
['A', 'D']        2017-10-21
['D', 'E']        2017-10-22
['A', 'E']        2017-10-22
['A', 'E', 'D']   2017-10-22
['C', 'B', 'E']   2017-10-23
['D', 'C', 'F']   2017-11-23
```

I need to make a new DataFrame from this DataFrame which would count the number of times the items show up in the list on each day. The count, therefore, would be across different rows on the same date..

For example, the new DataFrame would look like:

```
Users                        Date
[A=2, B=2, C=1, D=1]        2017-10-21
[E=3, D=2, A=2]             2017-10-22
[B=1, C=2, D=1, E=1, F=1]   2017-10-23
```

Some things to note: the all the items in the first dataset are lists with individual elements being strings. The Date column is of DateTime type.

I understand there would be a `groupby` function on the `Date` column but I can't figure out how to write the function that I would `apply` to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` and `apply` with `collections.Counter`:

```
df.groupby('Date').Users.sum().apply(collections.Counter, 1)

Date
2017-10-21    {'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 1, 'D': 1}
2017-10-22            {'D': 2, 'E': 3, 'A': 2}
2017-10-23            {'C': 1, 'B': 1, 'E': 1}
2017-11-23            {'D': 1, 'C': 1, 'F': 1}
Name: Users, dtype: object
```

If you have multiple columns that you want to count per group:

***Setup***

```
s = 'ABCDE'

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Users': [random.sample(s, random.randint(1, 5)) for _ in range(10)],
    'Tools': [random.sample(s, random.randint(1, 5)) for _ in range(10)],
    'Hours': [random.sample(s, random.randint(1, 5)) for _ in range(10)],
    'Date': ['2017-10-21', '2017-10-21', '2017-10-21', '2017-10-22',
    '2017-10-22', '2017-10-22', '2017-10-23', '2017-10-23', '2017-10-23', '2017-11-23']
})
```

#### Using `agg`:

```
df.groupby('Date').sum().agg({
    'Users': collections.Counter,
    'Tools': collections.Counter,
    'Hours': collections.Counter
})
```

```
                                               Users                                     Tools                                     Hours
Date
2017-10-21  {'C': 2, 'E': 2, 'A': 2, 'B': 2, 'D': 1}  {'E': 3, 'A': 2, 'B': 3, 'D': 2, 'C': 2}  {'B': 2, 'C': 2, 'E': 1, 'A': 1, 'D': 1}
2017-10-22  {'D': 2, 'A': 2, 'E': 1, 'C': 1, 'B': 2}  {'E': 2, 'B': 3, 'A': 3, 'D': 1, 'C': 1}  {'B': 1, 'C': 2, 'E': 2, 'A': 2, 'D': 2}
2017-10-23  {'B': 2, 'A': 2, 'D': 1, 'E': 1, 'C': 2}  {'D': 3, 'E': 2, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'A': 2}  {'C': 3, 'E': 2, 'D': 2, 'B': 1, 'A': 2}
2017-11-23                  {'D': 1, 'B': 1, 'C': 1}                                  {'B': 1}                          {'C': 1, 'E': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Further question: How would I do it if I had to do the same thing over multiple columns? Let's say Users, Tools, Work hours? All containing the same type of data (list of strings). Would I have to do them each separately?

Comment: Do you want to count them all together? Or separately?

Comment: Separately. All elements in Users would be used for counting that column only, Work hours elements for that column only and so on

Comment: @panaceanoob see my update for how to adapt this to multiple columns

Comment: probably a vague question, but I have another similar DataFrame with similar type of data in the rows. When I do the same thing on this DataFrame, I get a KeyError on the column names. Any idea why that's the case? I can give a small sample of the dataset if it is possible somehow.